# google map api drag and drop pin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add drag and drop google Api. I've made a map the but I do not know how to make it can be a drag and drop. in there i want make my latitude and longitude is auto fill when i drop the pin

here my view :

```html
 <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Latitude:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="latitude">
         <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Longitude</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="longitude">
```

here my script :

```html
<script>
              function initMap() {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  center: {lat: -7.0157404, lng: 110.4171283},
                  zoom: 12
                });
                var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
                    document.getElementById('pac-input'));

                var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
                map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
                });

                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                  infowindow.close();
                  marker.setVisible(false);
                  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                  if (!place.geometry) {
                    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                    return;
                  }

                  // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
                  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                  } else {
                    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
                  }
                  marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                    url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png',
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
                  }));
                  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                  marker.setVisible(true);

                  var address = '';
                  if (place.address_components) {
                    address = [
                      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                    ].join(' ');
                  }

                  var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                  var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng(); 

                  $("input[name=coordinate]").val(address);
                  $("input[name=latitude]").val(latitude);
                  $("input[name=longitude]").val(longitude);

                  infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

                // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
                // Autocomplete.
                function setupClickListener(id, types) {
                  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
                  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    autocomplete.setTypes(types);
                  });
                }

                setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
                setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
                setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
                setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
              }
            </script>               
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA5NI4m71IlUMe9iBGvzg36RzwFE7dLavs&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

and when i drag the pin its will auto change the point `latitude` and `longitude`

Comment: I've removed the Laravel tags, because that's a server-side PHP framework, which doesn't have any relevance to your question which is purely HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Consider the following article in the docs to make the marker draggable  -  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#draggable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make the marker draggable:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
  draggable: true
});
```

2. add a listener to it for the dragend event that updates the latitude and longitude:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
  document.getElementsByName('latitude')[0].value = marker.getPosition().lat();
  document.getElementsByName('longitude')[0].value = marker.getPosition().lng();
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c0sd3L21/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -7.0157404,
      lng: 110.4171283
    },
    zoom: 12
  });
  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
    draggable: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    document.getElementsByName('latitude')[0].value = marker.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementsByName('longitude')[0].value = marker.getPosition().lng();
  })

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon( /** @type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
      url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png',
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

    $("input[name=coordinate]").val(address);
    $("input[name=latitude]").val(latitude);
    $("input[name=longitude]").val(longitude);

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" />
<div id="type-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
  <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
  <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
  <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
  <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
</div>
<label for="inputIsiBerita">Latitude:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required name="latitude">
<label for="inputIsiBerita">Longitude</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" required name="longitude">
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: oke, but if i try it's only change latitude and longitute, not with the location, what i need to do next ?

Comment: Your question was how to update the latitude and longitude when you dragged and dropped the marker.  Only one question per question...  If you want to ask something else, ask another question (after verifying there isn't already a duplicate).

Comment: ahh oke, i ve been make new post, may u check and help again : [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322042/gmaps-api-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a marker you should use this code:

```
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(12, 12))
            .title("title")
            .snippet("snippet"));
```

and then all you have to do to make it draggable is by adding this:

```
   Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(12, 12))
                .title("title")
                .snippet("snippet")
                .draggable(true));
```

by making `draggable` true, it allows a marker to be dragged from one place to another.